# Cómo ocultar el atributo href de la etiqueta <A> a través de css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

(Hice una pregunta parecida a esta y alguien me la cerro, ni si quiera leyo lo que puse.)

Me encuentro trabajando para una empresa desarrolladora de software y estoy trabajando desde la parte de front-end (estoy empezando) y me asignaron de tarea ocultar el atributo href de la etiqueta A unicamente utilizando css, la idea es que cuando haga click en la etiqueta me redirija a donde voy pero que al pasar el cursor por encima, el navegador no me muestre la barra de estado ni lo que hay dentro del atributo. Me dijeron que viera esta página https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613273/how-to-hide-href-attribute-of-a-tag-via-css-when-using-window-print y que encontraría la solución y la verdad ya llevo 3 dias intentado y nada que logro hacerlo. (Me dijeron que por tema de seguridad no lo hicera pero la verdad a la empresa donde laboro lo necesita solo por un tema estetico y tengo que cumplir.)

Este es el codigo:

```
<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-center border-x" *ngIf="repairData.salidaProvisional">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="goToTabParts()"><img class="img-car" src="/o/sgto-detail- sinister/icons/ico_provisionally_exit_yellow.svg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Saludos, bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Seguro que la pregunta original no fue eliminada sin leer, puesto que para eliminar una pregunta, hay todo un proceso en el que intervienen distintas personas (y solo participan personas con bastante reputación en el sitio).

Comment: Respecto a lo que buscas, puedes usar lo que dice el enlace al que te enviaron: `a[href]:after { display:none; }`. Pon eso en tu CSS y ya no debería aparecer.

Comment: @Tupi la puse en la version en ingles, la misma pregunta y te agradezco mucho la respuesta y gracias por esa calida bienvenida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es probable que los navegadores actuales no permitan ocultar la URL de destino, tal vez por motivos de seguridad. Todos los enlaces mostrarán algo en la barra de estado, aunque sea solo la URL de página actual.

Ya que el `href` es invalidado por medio de javascript y estás usando el evento clic, creo que lo mejor es no usar enlace, aplicar el evento a la imagen y, desde CSS, cambiar el cursor.

```css
/* Esto no funciona */
a[href]:after{
    display: none;
}
/* Cursor cambia al pasar sobre la imagen */
.img-car {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="">Enlace</a><br>
<img class="img-car" src="/o/sgto-detail- sinister/icons/ico_provisionally_exit_yellow.svg" (click)="goToTabParts()">
```